# Axis2 : Http status 500

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

i'm working on axis 2 creating web services and trying to get the results in Json object format

i'm getting through this Exception ---> HTTP error 500 - [image]

Comment: Please post the server log and error stacktrace.

Comment: sorry for being late those are the first lines of server log and stacktrace 
15:36:31,506 ERROR [CommonsHTTPTransportSender] Mapped formatted JSON with namespaces are not supported in Axis2. Make sure that your request doesn't include namespaces or use the Badgerfish convention
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mapped formatted JSON with namespaces are not supported in Axis2. Make sure that your request doesn't include namespaces or use the Badgerfish convention............... The New Idiot

Answer (score -1):

Your version of jettison.jar is wrong.

Try use the 1.1 version.

See this bug for more information: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14352